# Different parts of regex matching same text depending on what comes afterwards

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex (in a Python program) to match strings that look like this:

```
             """(book "Moby Dick" (MLA) #foo ?bar baz)

             """(book "Moby Dick" (MLA))

             """(book "Moby Dick")
```

My regex is currently:

```
(?P<indent>\s*)("""|\'\'\'|blockquote:)(\((?P<type>\w*)\s*(["\'](?P<citation>.+?)["\'])?\s*(\((?P<format>\w+?)\))?(?P<other>.+?)\))?
```

The desired result is:

```
indent  [0-8]   `        `
type    [12-16] `book`
citation    [18-27] `Moby Dick`
format  [30-33] `MLA`
other   [34-44] ` #foo ?bar baz`
```

And for the first version of the string, this is what I get. However, for shorter versions of the string, the "other" group is capturing earlier parts of the text, so for the second version I am getting:

```
indent  [0-8]   `        `
type    [12-16] `book`
citation    [18-27] `Moby Dick`
other   [29-33] `(MLA`
```

And for the third I am getting:

```
indent  [0-8]   `        `
type    [12-16] `book`
other   [17-28] `"Moby Dick"`
```

So my question is, why is the "other" pattern being matched before the earlier patterns, and what can I do to get the "citation" and "format" parts of the pattern to match the intended text in the second and third cases?

Comment: Do you need the `other` and `indent` part? If not, you could simply make the `format` part optional like so: `\((?<type>\w+\b)[^'"]+['"](?<title>[^"']*)(?:['"\s]+\((?<format>[^)]+))?`, see a [working fiddle here](https://regex101.com/r/wK1tI8/1)

Comment: I do need them, yes. But Rohit Jain's solution solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `(?P<other>.+?)` pattern also optional to get your required result:

```
reg = r'(?P<indent>\s*)("""|\'\'\'|blockquote:)(\((?P<type>\w*)\s*(["\'](?P<citation>.+?)["\'])?\s*(\((?P<format>\w+?)\))?(?P<other>.+?)?\))?'
```

Since it was not optional, regex engine would at least need 1 character apart from last closing parenthesis to successfully match the regex. Since other pattern is `.+` and there is a closing parenthesis after that. Hence the last 2 strings, `other` was matched instead of `citation` and `format`.

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?P<indent>\s*)("""|\'\'\'|blockquote:)(\((?P<type>\w*)\s*(["\'](?P<citation>.+?)["\'])?\s*(\((?P<format>\w+?)\))?(?P<other>.+?)?\))?')
>>> 
>>> 
>>> s2 = '             """(book "Moby Dick" (MLA))'
>>> 
>>> m2 = reg.match(s2)
>>> m2.groupdict()
{'indent': '             ', 'citation': 'Moby Dick', 'type': 'book', 'other': None, 'format': 'MLA'}
>>> 
>>> s3 = '             """(book "Moby Dick")'
>>> m3 = reg.match(s3)
>>> 
>>> m3.groupdict()
{'indent': '             ', 'citation': 'Moby Dick', 'type': 'book', 'other': None, 'format': None}
```